# System.IO.UTF8 not found (installing PureScript)

Tags: haskell, utf-8, cabal, purescript

I'm trying to install PureScript on Ubuntu 14.04. I have the latest version of Haskell-Platform and have run `cabal update`. During `cabal install purescript` I get an error saying that the module `System.IO.UTF8` is not found. Googling reveals that [this is part of `utf8-string` and should be one of the exposed modules](https://github.com/ghc/packages-utf8-string/blob/master/utf8-string.cabal) when that package is installed.

However, when I install it, no such package is available:

```
ely@eschaton:~$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
ely@eschaton:~$ cabal --reinstall install utf8-string
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following will be installed:
utf8-string-1 (reinstall)
Warning: Note that reinstalls are always dangerous. Continuing anyway...
Configuring utf8-string-1...
Building utf8-string-1...
Preprocessing library utf8-string-1...
[1 of 5] Compiling Codec.Binary.UTF8.String ( Codec/Binary/UTF8/String.hs, dist/build/Codec/Binary/UTF8/String.o )
[2 of 5] Compiling Codec.Binary.UTF8.Generic ( Codec/Binary/UTF8/Generic.hs, dist/build/Codec/Binary/UTF8/Generic.o )
[3 of 5] Compiling Data.String.UTF8 ( Data/String/UTF8.hs, dist/build/Data/String/UTF8.o )
[4 of 5] Compiling Data.ByteString.UTF8 ( Data/ByteString/UTF8.hs, dist/build/Data/ByteString/UTF8.o )
[5 of 5] Compiling Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 ( Data/ByteString/Lazy/UTF8.hs, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Lazy/UTF8.o )
In-place registering utf8-string-1...
Installing library in /home/ely/.cabal/lib/utf8-string-1/ghc-7.6.3
Registering utf8-string-1...
Installed utf8-string-1
ely@eschaton:~$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import System.IO.UTF8

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `System.IO.UTF8'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

You can see that only 5 of the stated proposed libraries are compiled.

The [PureScript source definitely makes use](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/blob/master/hierarchy/Main.hs#L34) of `System.IO.UTF8`.

But `System.IO.UTF8` looks like a pretty old package that has not undergone changes in a long time (2+ years), so it's unlikely that this was a significant change in a recent version. To boot, PureScript is very new, and so would surely be based on newer versions of utf8-string if they were available.

So the question is: why isn't PureScript able to install this dependency on its own ... and why does the `cabal` installation of `utf8-string` fail to expose the `System.IO.UTF8` module as it suggests it should.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like `utf-string` was updated *today* (Jan 23) to [version `1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-1) which doesn't have `System.IO.UTF8` module anymore. That one is present in previous [version `0.3.8` of `utf-string`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-0.3.8).

And the `purescript` doesn't specify the [upper bound for `utf-string`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/blob/b0d5551f5837101dded528dfa371c9f3e5f70455/purescript.cabal#L35).

---

*EDIT* I made [a PR](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/pull/827) to workaround the [issue](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/825).
There is [more proper fix WIP](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/pull/826) too.

Comment: Just my luck! I will file an issue at the PureScript page.

Comment: Actually it looks like they have already [committed some changes to fix this](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/pull/826). Not sure what the best install policy will be until the package is updated. Looks like I picked a bad day to test out PureScript...

Comment: I just merged this into master, and made a release on Hackage and GitHub, so you should be good now.